# How to use NEXT and TO in ACSL BASIC?

Tags: theory, basic

I have the following program:

```
X$="":Y$=""
A$="UNITEDSTATESOFAMERICA"
FOR J = 1 TO LEN(A$)
  IF MID$(A$, J, 1)>MID$(A$, LEN(A$)+1-J, 1)
NEXT J
PRINT Y$
END
```

What do the commands TO and NEXT do? I know they are loops, but how are they used?

Answer (score 0):

In the BASIC Programming Language:

`TO` - indicates the right bound of the range in the loop;

and

`NEXT identifier` - increments `identifier` by 1.

---

In your case, `FOR J = 1 TO LEN(A$)` would translate to `for loop`, which initializes your iteration variable `J` to 1, has a halting condition `J <= 21`(*because the length of A$ is 21*), and increments iteration variable `J` by 1, per each iteration.

Comment: How can I use TO, though? It's a range, so there's no set value, which makes it hard. And how does NEXT increment J?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please have a look again, I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR variable=<begining> TO <ending> STEP <step. Default is 1>
```

… initialize your loop and tells that each iteration should re-start after this point. Default behavour is to increment the variable at each loop (therefore, performing a "+1" operation) but you may specify other value, especially negative ones, which will be required if the beginning is higher than the final value.

```
NEXT variable
```

…both indicates the end of the loop AND commands the interpreter to perform another iteration, going back to top of the loop. You need a dedicated instruction for this because, as you may have noticed, BASIC doesn't use blocks such as `{ … }` or such.

The reason why it's necessary to pass the variable after `NEXT` is to distinguish which loop you're talking about, in case of multiple nested loops statements. You may also nest multiple variables. For example:

```
FOR X=1 TO 10
FOR Y=1 TO 10
PRINT X;" * ";Y;" = ";X*Y
NEXT Y
NEXT X
```

… can also be written:

```
FOR X=1 TO 10
FOR Y=1 TO 10
PRINT X;" * ";Y;" = ";X*Y
NEXT Y,X
```

Note that passing a variable to `NEXT` remains optional. If you don't, the statement will apply to the « closest » loop (I don't remember, though, if it's gonna the closest in the code or the latest called).